# How to make game like this by AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

[image]

> how to make game sort letter or guess pic Contains letters and spaces
>   can I use switch case or there is another way

Comment: It's already a fourth or fifth clone with the same question.

Comment: This makes my day! But it's kind of sad. The time and effort that is going into creating now 4 different accounts here and re-asking the same question with different pictures and every time getting the post immediately down voted and flagged. And I'm pretty sure asking the OP for samples of the code he has tried has so far resulted in zero posted code. If 1996 Angel is even bothering to read this, which I doubt, let me restate that this is not a code writing service. You are showing zero research and zero effort. Post some code that you have tried and explain what problem you are having.

Comment: If you reply by editing your post and actually adding the code you are trying to work with, I promise to take pity on you and post a real answer.

Answer (score 3):

> can I use switch case

Yes of course. A switch block is just one way to do a conditional statement.  If you are actually to the point in your programming skills to begin making a game like this, then you probably shouldn't have to ask such a simple question. This is not intended to put you down. I'm trying to encourage you to find the right questions to ask. Here is a conditional block to help you figure out the right question to ask:

```
If you already have working buttons
    and you already have working text fields
        then post the code in your question and someone can look at it and help you.
else if you already have an .as file and a .fla file you are working with 
     post that code and ask for help making buttons or text fields
 else if you don't have a an .fla file or .as file
      then welcome to square one. Go find you very first tutorial on the Internet and come back when you get stuck on a specific problem
```

Comment: They should put a big billboard on the site and write:"Please don't ask how to make app like this".